# Splash screen doesnt load on when running on Emulator with API<24

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

My app is crashing on the splash screen on API <24. I have checked step by step and the logcat is giving an error on the setContentView line when inflating the layout.

is setContent view not supported on API<24 or is it somehting in my layout file shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
    android:layout_width="112dp"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's a problem of vector drawable?

Comment: Hi @Md.Asaduzzaman, how do i fix it for API<24. i know this is the issue because running it on nexus One API 23, the app crashes and running on API 24 it is fine.

Comment: post the splash activity code too, this looks fine. and also post the exception and error messages

Comment: Hi @Md.Asaduzzaman, you pointed me in the right direction. code was perfect. it seems i pasted the iages in drawables-v24. i moved it into `drawables` and it is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images were pasted into the wrong drawables folder. i had it initially in `drawables v-24`. after moving it to `drawables` it is working fine.